# Lock+HasMap or ConcurrentHashMap in my case?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, java-7, concurrenthashmap

I have a `Map<String, Queue<?>>` and each time I have to put a couple (key, value) I need to get the not thread-safe Queue associated with that key and add a value to it (if key exist). Because I need to update an existing value (queue) I think that the best way is to use a ReentrantLock (the synchronized block or synchronized (object) in Java < 1.5) and not ConcurrentHashMap.

Is that correct or can I use ConcurrentHashMap instead of HashMap + Lock? I think ConcurrentHashMap is more efficient in get operation but I don't know if could be the right solution here.

```
    private static ReentrantLock lock_Vqueue = new ReentrantLock();
    private static HashMap<String,Queue<DocumentObjectHolder>> cacheData = new HashMap<String,Queue<DocumentObjectHolder>>();
        /**
         * insert element in the tail 
         * sort the elements by priority 
         * @param obj a DocumentObjectHolder Object
         */
        public static void add(String key, DocumentObjectHolder obj){
            ReentrantLock lock = lock_Vqueue; //performance side effect
            try{
                Queue<DocumentObjectHolder>priorityProcessingVirtualQueue;
                lock.lock();
                    if (!cacheData.containsKey(key)){
                        priorityProcessingVirtualQueue = new PriorityQueue<DocumentObjectHolder>(1, new PriorityComparator());
                        cacheData.put(key, priorityProcessingVirtualQueue);
                    }
                    priorityProcessingVirtualQueue = cacheData.get(key);
                    priorityProcessingVirtualQueue.add(obj);
                    cacheData.put(key, priorityProcessingVirtualQueue);
            }finally {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }

        /**
         * 
         * @return DocumentObjectHolder instance from head of list (FIFO)
         */
        public DocumentObjectHolder get(String key){
            ReentrantLock lock = lock_Vqueue; //performance side effect
            Queue<DocumentObjectHolder>priorityProcessingVirtualQueue;
            try {
                lock.lock(); 
                 if (cacheData.containsKey(key)){
                     priorityProcessingVirtualQueue = cacheData.get(key);
                     return priorityProcessingVirtualQueue.poll();
                 }
                 return null;
            }finally{
                lock.unlock();
            }
        }
}
```

Is this code right or could it be more performant?

Comment: How much contention for the map do you expect?

Comment: yes, you should avoid doing double gets in both methods.  call `get()` and check the result for null instead of calling `containsKey()`.

Comment: and yes, you could make this more performant by using a ConcurrentHashMap, because you could reduce the locking to each specific queue instead of locking all queues for every update.

Comment: I think for your case it would be better to use ConcurrentHashMap because you add items obe by one, not in batch. So you're code is working basicly the same ways as ConcurrentHashMap, but is more complicated

Comment: also, you could use PriorityBlockingQueue for the queue impl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have two separate atomic instructions which need to be synchronized with.

1. Putting a new queue into the Map
2. Putting an object into the Queue

Here are my suggestions.

1. Continue to use a `ConcurrentHashMap`.  You still need to `put` into the map and you may as well do it safely with a CHM.
2. Use a `BlockingQueue`.  In this case you can use a `PriorityBlockingQueue`.
3. If you cannot do (2) then `synchronize` on the queue from the Map.

So 1 & 3 would look like:

```
    public static void add(String key, DocumentObjectHolder obj){
        Queue<DocumentObjectHolder> priorityProcessingVirtualQueue= cacheData.get(key);
        if(priorityProcessingVirtualQueue== null){
             Queue<DocumentObjectHolder> temp = new PriorityQueue<DocumentObjectHolder>(1, new PriorityComparator());
             queue = cacheData.putIfAbsent(key, temp);
             if(priorityProcessingVirtualQueue== null){ 
                  priorityProcessingVirtualQueue= temp;
             } 
        }
        synchronized(priorityProcessingVirtualQueue){
            priorityProcessingVirtualQueue.add(obj);
        }
    }
```

The only difference needed for 1 & 2 is the absence of `synchronized`.

The reason we know this is thread-safe is because even if 2 or more threads enter `if(queue == null)` only one will succeed in `putIfAbsent`.  The threads which lose will assign `queue` to equal the Queue that was successfully put in.  If a thread wins (queue == null is true) then we will assign the queue to be the one *we* created (we being the winning thread).